# Empty nodes when creating SOM

Tags: r, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to create a SOM map based on records with different discrete classifications (tags) like the example below

```
Record                   Tag1       Tag2       Tag3      Tag4
3555                        1          0          0         0
6447                        1          0          0         0
5523                        1          0          1         0
7550                        1          0          1         0
6330                        1          0          1         0 
2451                        1          0          0         0
4308                        1          0          1         0
8917                        0          0          0         0
4780                        1          0          1         0
6802                        1          0          1         0
2021                        1          0          0         0
5792                        1          0          1         0
5475                        1          0          1         0 
4198                        1          0          0         0
223                         1          0          1         0
4811                        1          0          1         0
678                         1          0          1         0
```

The problem I am facing is that there are many empty nodes in the SOM. From what I have read, each node should have 5-10 records but still this is not working. This is an example of what the nodes look like:

[image: Example of how the nodes look]

Could it be that all observations are very different from one another?

Comment: How much data do you have & how many nodes are there in your SOM?

Comment: at the moment I have ~10000 observations with ~10 variables. I already tried multiple node combinations, from 100x50 to 10x10 and I always get empty nodes

Comment: If you have ten binary variables, there are a maximum of 2^10 = 1024 different possible input vectors. How many of those 1024 possible combinations actually appear in your data?

Answer (score 1):

SOM is able to tolerate missing data, so some nodes might be empty due to incompletely defined data. In terms of using a SOM as a histogram, you might want to have an average of 50 records per node for statistical significance. This heuristic is given in http://docs.unigrafia.fi/publications/kohonen_teuvo/. For your data (10k observations), that would mean that a dimension like 10x20 could make sense.

If the node is empty, then you might use the nearest neighbors method for selecting a label. You can take a vote among the nearest neighbors (some number of neighbors of your choosing). But in a 200 node map, it would seem curious if there were more than a handful of nearly empty nodes.